# Find the distribution of age of the Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process, renewal-processes

Let $(N_t)_t$ be a Poisson process of intensity $\lambda$ with arrival time $(T_k)_{k\geq 0}$ and inter-arrival time $(X_k)_{k\geq 1}$. For a fixed time $t$, the $\textbf{age}$ is defined as $A_t=t-T_{N_t}$. I am trying to find the distribution of this random variable.

If we condition on $X_1$, we can find that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(A_t>y\,|\,X_1=x)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&1,\quad & x\geq t \\
&0,\quad  & t-y\leq x<t \\
&\mathbb{P}(A_{t-x}>y), &x<t-y.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation} 
So
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_t>y) = \int_{0}^{t-y} \mathbb{P}(A_{t-x}>y) dF(x)+\int_{t}^\infty dF(x).
$$
But I have no idea what to do next. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow why is $\mathbb P(t - T_{N_t} > y | X_1 = x) $ certain if $x \ge t$? I think the probability of that should depend on $y$, so I think there's something wrong with your conditional probability distribution.

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214248/age-and-residual-life-time-of-the-poisson-process